# Prove if $G:V \to V^*$ is an isomorphism then $G \circ f = f^*\circ G$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be finite dimensional linear space over $\mathbb{R}$ with dot product $\langle - , - \rangle:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $f:V\to V$ be linear transformation such that $\forall \alpha, \beta \in V, \langle f(\alpha), \beta\rangle=\langle\alpha, f(\beta)\rangle$

Prove if $G:V \to V^*$ is an isomorphism with condition:

$G(\alpha)=\psi \iff \forall \beta\in V \ \ \psi(\beta)=\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle$

then $G \circ f =  f^*\circ G$

Comment: Is V a vector space? What is $\langle x,y \rangle$ ? An inner product?

Comment: Is $f$ an endomorphism of $V$, and $f^*$ the pull-back?

Comment: sorry, see edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the direct approach!

If $v\in V$, $G(f(v)) = (G\circ f)(v)$.  By assumption, for all $w\in V$, $((G\circ f)(v))(w) = \langle f(v),w \rangle$.

How about $f^\ast \circ G$?  For $v,w\in V$, we have $((f^\ast \circ G)(v))(w) = (f^\ast (G(v)))(w) = (G(v))(f(w)) = \langle v,f(w) \rangle$.